# Handling of '--' in arguments of /bin/sh: POSIX vs implementations by Bash/Dash/FreeBSD's sh

Tags: shell, posix

I want to call /bin/sh, and use the -c option to pass the command '+x', i.e., to execute a program called '+x', whose name begins with a plus sign.

Since '+x' is interpreted by /bin/sh as an option (specifically, disable the 'x' option), /bin/sh must be prevented from interpreting it as an option.  I get the following different results depending on the /bin/sh I use:

(1) First variant:

```
/bin/sh -c -- +x
```

Using Dash and Bash on Linux:  The command +x is executed.

Using FreeBSD's sh:  The command -- is executed, and the +x option is set.

(2) Second variant:

```
/bin/sh -c +x
```

Using Dash and Bash on Linux:  The +x option is set, and there is an error because the option -c is missing an argument.

Using FreeBSD's sh:  The command +x is executed.

(3) Third variant:

```
/bin/sh -c - +x
```

Using Dash and Bash on Linux:  +x is executed.

Using FreeBSD's sh:  The command - is executed and the option +x is set.

(4) Fourth variant:  (ADDED as suggested in the comments)

```
/bin/sh -c+x
```

Using Dash and Bash on Linux:  Invalid/Illegal option '+'

Using FreeBSD's sh:  Bad -c option

---

My question:  What does POSIX prescribe?

I'm reading the POSIX specification for sh here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html

Quoting from it:  "A single hyphen shall be treated as the first operand and then ignored. If both '-' and "--" are given as arguments, or if other operands precede the single hyphen, the results are undefined."

I'm not sure whether that quote also applies to a single dash placed just after '-c'.

So, which one is right, Dash/Bash or FreeBSD?  Or, if both are right because POSIX allows both, how to do this portably?

Comment: For good measure: what does `/bin/sh -c+x` do?

Comment: @bishop I don't think so. `/bin/sh` will just see the arguments `-c` and `+x`, so `getopt()` should treat that as `/bin/sh -c +x`.

Comment: The POSIX reference for `sh` is here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew; I updated the link.  (I was confused by their frames.)

Comment: Rhymoid:  /bin/sh -c+x  gives an error with all three shells:  see the edit to the question

Comment: Portability tricks: a full or relative path to `+x`, a more conventionally named link to `+x`, or `sh -c 'command +x'` ([`command` is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/command.html), though it may be built in causing problems: `xargs` or `at now` might work.).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `sh -c ./+x` or `sh -c /path/to/+x`?

Comment: Also relevant, in terms of "what does POSIX require?" is http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html -- see in particular Guideline 10.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the question "What does Posix prescribe" is already present in the OP. But the important feature of the Posix standard is not highlighted: **the `-c` option does not take an argument**.

You can see this in the Synopsis:

```
sh -c [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
      command_string [command_name [argument...]]
```

What the `-c` flag does is cause the positional parameters ("operands") to be interpreted in a different way. Without `-c`, they are interpreted as `[command_file [argument...]]`:

```
sh [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
   [command_file [argument...]]
```

That, by the way, is why `sh -c+x` is an error. If `-c` took an argument, then it would be legal to include the argument in the same word.

So, to answer the more specific questions:

1. Posix says "A single hyphen shall be treated as the first operand and then ignored...". Does that apply to a `-` immediately following `-c`?

   A: Yes, it does. `-c` is a complete option, and the `-` is therefore an operand. By contrast, `-` in `-o -` would not be treated as an operand. (It would be treated as an invalid option name.)
2. Which one is right, Dash/Bash or FreeBSD?

   A: In this case, Dash and Bash are Posix-compliant, and FreeBSD's sh is not. FreeBSD's shell considerably predates the current Posix specification, and I don't believe it ever purported to be fully compliant to any Posix specification.
3. How do I portably use `sh` to run a command whose name begins with a `+`?

   A: I would think the following would work on any shell:

   ```
   sh -c " +x"
   ```

   `" +x"` will not be recognized as an option because it doesn't start with a `+` or `-`, and `sh -c` causes the operand to be parsed as a shell command, so leading whitespace will be ignored. I don't have a copy of FreeBSD's `ash` to play with just now, so I welcome corrections.

   Or you could use a simple compound command:

   ```
   sh -c "{ +x; }"
   ```

   Possibly clearest (assuming the shell you're using implements the Posix-standard builtin `command`) is:

   ```
   sh -c "command +x"
   ```

Comment: Typo in answer: `"+ x"` --> `" +x"`.

Comment: Same here: I thought `sh -c ' +x'` would work, but I don't have FreeBSD to test and @Rhymoid's comment dissuaded me. I think that was for the better, because `' +x'` seems tricky (and maybe brittle). `sh -c 'command +x'` seems more clear to intent while being portable.

Comment: If the space is too weird, `sh -c ':; +x'` should also work.

Comment: @bishop: getopt definitely treats a space at the beginning of an argument as a non-option character. That's abundantly clear. So I don't see what Rhymoid's comment has to do with the suggestion. Another possibly not-so-wierd option would be `sh -c "{ +x; }"`

Comment: @bishop: to be clearer, I think your suggestion was `sh -c '-x'`, to which Rhymoid replied that the quotes will be removed before the argument is passed to the utility, which is true (and important). In `sh -c ' -x'`, the quotes are also removed, but not the space character. So it's (IMO) neither tricky nor brittle; it is simply leveraging the way shells work.

Comment: @rici Oh, whoops, I can't see my deleted comment, but I must have totally mistyped that in a crucial way, and I thought Rhymoid was saying it wasn't working on FreeBSD. (The problems of doing three things at once on a Friday.) Anyhow, I like your alternate suggestion with the list syntax, b/c the `' +x'` approach just seems like it'll invite a maintainer to delete the quotes or be hard to read.